# Use python module in a package without knowing the module's name

Tags: python

I have a package with some modules in it:

```
/package/
   mod1
   mod2
   mod3
```

Which I imported like so:

```
from package import *
```

Now I want iterate through the modules in the package without knowing the module's name so if more modules are added the code does not have to be changed, like so:

```
for module in package
   module.some_method()
```

Can this be done?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the `*` import does.  It's *not* going to import submodules automatically.

Comment: Use the `dir` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the modules from the package if the package imports them in it's `__init__.py`. For example:

```
# package/__init__.py
import mod1
import mod2
import mod3
```

Then you could import the package and just look for all members of that package that are a "module" type:

```
import types
import package

for mod in package.__dict__.values():
  if type(mod) == types.ModuleType:
    print mod, 'is a module!'
```

Comment: This works. I can access the attributes etc in the module.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import submodules from a package unless you list them within the `__all__` list within the `__init__.py` file within your package.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

At some point, you need to know the modules names. This could work for you, but it could have some unintended consequences.

Answer (score -1):

Not always there are distributed modules packaged as one package in python. It cannot be done.

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this:-**

```
import inspect
import yourmodule

all_module = inspect.getmembers(yourmodule,inspect.ismodule)
print(all_module)#will list all related module
```